# Does Azure Active Directory App Model v2 support graph api?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

i am not able to consent the graphi api permission in active directory v2 (app model v2). I tried below:
Incremental and dynamic consent example

[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-compare/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160712004836/https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-compare/)

Error i got:
The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.windows.net/directory.read is not valid.

[consent url](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=406d2e0b-94fd-47d2-bbb9-98db6988c0d9&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44326/&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20https://graph.windows.net/%20directory.read&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=_G6uVC6iYrmthRfv0Yo8W1uGjvfdZmMrGmXDW3Me02EDWyQCHlJGMfmWFDAOfvS9fatV6wCNWX2ySfgR_3ai1lbeIaz5aqicxfh9KUnLBH8VHghtmkMT-rL7sJNPcvDriRLQKPzcYLqHHVxQv8Dcm-bHtufvpKOsXfoWtlu6CHg&nonce=635936241759998382.ZWJkMzc4ZTItZGE4MC00NDc3LWE0NDUtOTBkYjAzNzdlYTJjMDc5Mzg1ZjctMjhmNS00YTliLTljOTItNDk3ZGIyZTQ1MmMy)

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com) partially supports the App Model v2 - specifically the outlook scopes (e.g. mail.read) and directory scopes (e.g. directory.read.all). Other scopes such as File and Sites don't.

The Azure AD Graph (https://graph.windows.net) does not support the App Model v2 at all.

Directory.Read isn't being accepted because it isn't a valid scope, you're either after User.Read or Directory.Read.All

See http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes for more info.